# Why won't a ViewProperty animation run more than once?

Tags: android

I've got a simple View property animation attached to a button.  The animation works perfectly on the first button press.  However, on subsequent clicks no animation occurs.  The log proves the button is being pressed.  Is there something I'm missing?  Here is the code:

```
    Button handle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HandleButton);
    Button wheel1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Wheel1);
    handle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        @Override        
        public void onClick(View v) {     
        Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked");       
        ViewPropertyAnimator spinWheel1 = wheel1.animate().rotationX(360*8).setDuration(2000);
        }    
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Button handle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HandleButton);
handle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        @Override        
        public void onClick(View v) {     
        Log.d(TAG, "Button Clicked");       
            spinWheel1 = wheel1.animate().rotationXBy(360*8).setDuration(2000);
            }    
        });
```

Try using rotationXBy instead of rorationX, you may also want to try using object animator as you can set start and end rotation degree.

Comment: Thanks!  rotationXBy did it!  I didn't realize that the rotated value was being retained.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(spinWheel1, View.ROTATION, 0, 360*8);
     animator.setDuration(2000);
     animator.start();
```

your button already has rotated to 360*8
By adding the 0 your animation will start all over again

Comment: I was hoping your idea would work but rotationX only accepts a single parameter.  Did you mean something else?